# No signal after adding a secondary video card

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

ThinkStation D10, video OK with FX Quadro 4600.
After adding a second FX Quadro 4600 (from other ThinkStation D10), I have no signal (no display).

I used to do this on two different ThinkStation S10 before with other video cards without any problem.

This happened last week and I don't have found any clue.

An help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, Nicolas

Comment: Have you connected the SLI bridge? Are all necessary molex plugs connected to the motherboard?

Comment: What's that ? Have I to buy a SLI bridge ? sorry I am not a superuser ! :-)

Comment: BIOS conflicts mean you're likely to have a great deal of difficulty using two of the same make & model of video adapter alongside one another, unless they're in what's known as "SLI" configuration (or "Crossfire" if you're AMD). This configuration requires the adapters to communicate outside the PCIe bus, which needs a special connector called an "SLI bridge". If you're interested in trying out SLI, [Nvidia's Quadro SLI FAQ](http://www.nvidia.fr/object/quadro_sli_faq_in.html) is probably a good place to start. Otherwise, replace one or the other card with a different make or model.

Comment: I have tested with two different graphic cards, no result. Is it dependent on the motherboard ? cause, I never had this kind of issue with Thinkstation S10. I just had to plug the additional graphic card... so it's very strange... (no need for a connector SLI)

Comment: SLI should not be needed. One of the cards should generate output. Did you try plugging in the monitors in both cards?